# get Data, on item selected item from spinner. and send through onClick in Button

Tags: android, json, post, android-spinner

I have passed data to Spinner. This is my JSON data,

I have a spinner, In which I am passing this below JSON. this is data from  post method.

My plan is to get below data in Spinner. After Selecting batch, I will click Button below, which will send "Batch_Id" to next activity it will take "Batch_Id" from selected "Batch" from spinner. because next activity wants Batch_Id to fetch data from URL.

I have done parsing of "Batch". but I am stuck into second section where I want to send Batch_Id based on which Batch Selected.

```
[
{
  "Batch_Id": "1",
  "Batch": "2016-21"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "2",
  "Batch": "2015-20"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "3",
  "Batch": "2014-19"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "4",
  "Batch": "2013-18"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "5",
  "Batch": "2012-17"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "6",
  "Batch": "2014-17"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "7",
  "Batch": "2015-18"
},
{
  "Batch_Id": "8",
  "Batch": "2016-19"
}
]
```

I have parsed "Batch" in Spinner, Now I want to get Batch_Id position wise, like if i select 2016-19, then i will get "batch_id" equals 8.

I have tried this,

```
          final JSONArray jsonArraybatch = jsonArray.getJSONArray(1);
            JSONArray jsonArraysection = jsonArray.getJSONArray(2);
            JSONArray jsonArraysubject = jsonArray.getJSONArray(3);
            JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonArrayTeacherName.getJSONObject(0);
            teachername = jsonResponse.optString("teacher_name");
            teacherid = jsonResponse.optString("teacher_id");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArraybatch.length(); i++)

            {
                final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArraybatch.getJSONObject(i);
                final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.batch_spinner);

                String batch = jsonObject.optString("Batch");


                batchlist.add(batch);
                mySpinner
                        .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(PutCredentials.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                batchlist));

                mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectedBatch = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        batchid = jsonObject.optString("Batch_Id");


                    }
```

Comment: what have tried so far .Show your code for the same

Comment: Actually I have shown you only a part of JSON because I have already parsed Batch in Spinner. But my problem is I want to send Batch_Id to next activity on Button Click.

Comment: see `OnItemSelectedListener#onItemSelected`, the last parameter is `id`, your adapter has just to override `getItemId` method

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/fNuDfLrj) you have full working code, just add it to `Activity#onCreate` to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Create model class:

```
class BatchModel{

 String batchId;

 String batchName;

}
```

batchlist variable must be BatchModel type

```
 ex: List<BatchModel> list= new ArrayList<>();


 String batch = jsonObject.optString("Batch");
 String batchid = jsonObject.optString("Batch_Id");

 BatchModel bm= new BatchModel();
 bm.batchId=batchid;
 bm.batch=batch;
 list.add(bm);
```

SpinnerAdapter class

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BatchModel> {

public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ,List<BatchModel> listItems) {
    super(context, resource, listItems);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
    }

    BatchModel bm = getItem(position);

    if (v != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.batch);
         tt1.setText(bm.batch);

    }

    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: and you need to use custom Arrayadapter or base adapter to set the value.

Comment: if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.batch);
         tt1.setText(bm.batch);

    }  what is p here?

Comment: it's view. i typed on code in this page itself.via mobile. i update it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep this method outside:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectedBatch = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        batchid = jsonObject.optString("Batch_Id");


                    }
```

Now you can use this one to find your batchid:

```
@Override


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectedBatch = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        for(int i = 0;jsonArraybatch.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArraybatch.getJSONObject(i);
       if (selectedBatch.equals(jsonObject.optString("Batch"))){
           batchid = jsonObject.optString("Batch_Id");
   }
}


                    }
```

Comment: it is giving me batch_id = 8, for any selection.. bcoz there is a for loop, due to that it is giving 8 all the time. btw thanx.

Comment: you could explicitly create  hashmap while creating adapter where-batch will be key and batch_id will be its corresponding value then simply just find the batch_id in its value pair in hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Create a skeleton `Batch` with two *membervariables* `batchName` and `batchId`
   and write a custom adapter for that spinner passing `Array<Batch>`
2. Use a Map as reference.

**Using Custom Adapter for spinner**

**Adapter**

```
   public class SchoolSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ArrayList<School> mSchools;
   private Context mContext;

   public SchoolSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<School> schools) {
       mContext = ctx;
       mSchools = schools;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return mSchools.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return mSchools.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.spinner_text, null);
       }
       ((TextView) convertView).setText(mSchools.get(position).getName());
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

**layout inflated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Set this adapter to your spinner

```
spinner.setAdapter(new SchoolAdapter(this,schoollist));
```

**Using Map as Reference**

**Prepare value for spinner**

```
String[] spinnerArray = new String[Province_ID.size()];
HashMap<String,String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < Province_ID.size(); i++)
{
   spinnerMap.put(Province_NAME.get(i),Province_ID.get(i));
   spinnerArray[i] = Province_NAME.get(i);
}
```

**Set value to spinner**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Get value to spinner**

```
String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String id = spinnerMap.get(name);
```